# connect Powervault tl2000 over network for old backup exec tapes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backupexec, dell-powervault

I need to connect a Powervault tl2000 to one of our rebuilt server to recover some data from an old tape. We don't use BackupExec or the PowerVault any more so I downloaded a trial version of BE2012 for 60 days and installed it on one of our physical Server 2008R2.

The PowerVault remained connected exactly as before and from what I could figure out it was done via network. My problem is that I have never seen a solution like this before (we have a PowerVault MD connected via SCSI), have never worked with a tape PowerVault and have no idea how I can gain access to the data via the network.

The Vault is connected on a different subnet which I got access to and managed to get into the web interface. All the Libraries seem intact and in good condition.

Could someone point me in the right direction of getting these tapes mapped to the Windows Server OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard network port is just for management. If that is all you have then you need to connect it via SCSI for the actual data.

It is also possible that you might have an iscsi bridge card in which case you would need to run the ms iscsi initiator on the machine with backup exec and connect to the device.

See the manual here
ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powervault/powervault-tl2000_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply James, I've had a further a look and there is definitely a bridge card on the TL2000, it has the iscsi cable looping into it and 2 RJ45s coming out. We also have a an Equilogic SAN that is connected in exactly the same way and is on the same ip range. The problem is I can easily connect to the Equilogic SAN ipaddress via the MS iSCSI initiator and it will show me all the LUNs available on the SAN but if I try to discover the ip address of the TL2000 it just says connection failed

Comment: Thank you for the nudge in the right direction James. I just did an IP scan on the range and found there were 2 more ip addresses nearby. punched those into the iSCSI initiator and 2 LUNs connected and BE drivers installed, now just have to figure out how to configure BE2012